# Customized thousand separator for string type variable

Tags: python, string, performance, python-3.x

I want to format my string containing both decimal and floating point using thousand separator. I've tried:

```
"{:,}".format()
```

but it is not working with an argument of string type!

```
>>> num_str = "123456.230"
>>> "{:,}".format(num_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'.
>>>
```

Googled for solution(s) but couldn't find any solution(s) that satisfy my needs.

My sample input: `"123456.0230"`

My desired sample output to be: `"123,456.0230"`

I wrote my own code which is as follows:

```
input_str = ''
output_str = ''
lenth = 0

input_str = input("Input a number: ")

for i in input_str:
    if input_str[lenth] == '.':
        break
    lenth += 1

if lenth % 3 == 0:
    pos_separator = 3
else:
    pos_separator = lenth % 3

for i in range(0, lenth):
    if i == pos_separator:
        output_str += ',' + input_str[i]
        pos_separator += 3
    else:
        output_str += input_str[i]

output_str += input_str[lenth:]

print("Output String: ", output_str)
```

Sampe 1:

```
>>> Input a number: 123456.0230
>>> Output String:  123,456.0230
```

Sample 2:

```
>>> Input a number: 12345.
>>> Output String:  12,345.
```

Working okay but is there any other way better than this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* just make it a float and *then* apply it:

```
>>> "{:,}".format(float(num_str))
'123,456.23'

>>> "{:,}".format(float(12345))
'12,345.0'
```

You can also utilize the `'g'` specifier to remove trailing zeros if required:

```
>>> "{:,g}".format(float(12345))
'12,345'
```

As pointed out by @ user2357112 in a comment, you optimally could import `Decimal` and feed that into `.format` instead:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> "{:,}".format(Decimal(num_str))
'123,456.230'
```

---

Since you also have cases as the trailing dot, where it needs to be preserved and since I cannot think of a way `.format` can do this on its own, create a little function that will append `'.'` if it exists and do nothing if it doesn't:

```
def format_str(s):
    fstr = "{:,}".format(Decimal(s))
    return fstr + ('.' if s[-1] == '.' else '')
```

Which, for some test cases:

```
for s in ['12345', '12345.', '1234.5']:
    print(format_str(s))
```

yields:

```
12,345
12,345.
1,234.5
```

Comment: You could also call `decimal.Decimal` instead of `float`, to avoid rounding and exactly preserve trailing zeros.

Comment: @ Jim and & user2357112: Thank you guys! works great except for the case: >>> num_str = "123456." >>> {:,}".format(Decimal(num_str)) >>> '123,456' (which returns without dot as it should be).

But I'm currently working on a calculator project with GUI/PyQt5 which needs the mentioned case for displaying user input by keyPressEvent(). I guess there is no other way but the customized way to satisfy this need. if there is any other way then please let me know. Regards.

Comment: @smearumi you can create a customized version for that that is even shorter, take a look at my updated answer and see if it does the trick.

Comment: @ Jim: Thanks! 100% perfect trick and 100% satisfaction! Thumbs Up! :))